# Finding constraints that cause solution infeasibility in the nurse scheduling example using OR-Tools

Tags: python, scheduling, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am still a beginner with constraint programming and I am currently trying to implement a nurse scheduling problem in Python using [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling#nurse_scheduling).

Particularly during debbuging I often come across situations in which the CpSolver is unable to find a solution and I cannot figure out why. So I wondered, is there a way to trace back which constraint/s (are likely to have) caused no feasible solution?

I have searched through the documentation but couldn't find such a function or any documentation on it. However, I am sure this is a common problem and there should be a solution to this. Can anyone advise me what the function is or where I can find documentation on this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is automatic tool yet. See [github.com/google/or-tools/issues/973](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/973)

Answer (score 0):

The discussion in https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/973#issuecomment-817635488%3E announced some new functions in version 8.2

cp_model.AddAssumptions({a, b, c});

response.sufficient_assumptions_for_infeasibility()

which look like they find (one?) minimal conflict. This may be what you're looking for.

Laurent Perron explained in the discussion "Each constraint has an enforcement literal.
Then you maximize the sum of enforcement literals."